# Analog isolator to Differential Amp to Differential ADC

Tags: analog, adc, differential-amplifier, single-supply-op-amp

I'm using an ADC from Linear Technology, [LTC2344-16](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltc2344-16.html) ​, and i have to measure an isolated voltage through an analog isolator [TLP7820](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/eu/semiconductor/product/isolators-solid-state-relays/isolation-amplifiers-isolated-delta-sigma-modulators/detail.TLP7820.html) and a FDA,like in figure below:

[image]

​I draw the schematic with the goal to be "multi-purpose" so the input voltage divider can be configure as "balanced", with central gnd or single ended .. anyway the analog isolator is used in its "optimal linear range" 0-200mv as described in the application note.
the isolator has a fixed gain of 8,2 v/v, so its output is in the range 0-1,64v.

I used then FDA [LTC1992](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltc1992.html) to amplify the differential signal to match the the input range of the ADC.
Since i want to use the configuration indicated in the table (0-2,5v) i choose the resistors to configure a gain of 1,51 (2,5/1,64). This is the simulation i did with the DiffAmp Calculator from analog Devices:

[image]

In my analog chain I chose to get to the entrance of the ADC with an analog range of +-2.5v but I think I had badly interpreted the  [datasheet of the LTC2344](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltc2344-16.html)

I want to use the external Vref configuration, in order to use the 0-2.5 or +-2.5V input range (negative range it should be useful to use the circuit to measure a current using a shunt resistor, changing some parts in the input stage)

[image]

In configuration indicated by the arrow, it speaks of analogue range of +2.5V but in reality the "full range" can be +-5v (ie VDD).So could I also use Vref 2.5 as VOCM, as long as I stay in a 2.5V differential range?​
in other words i wanna ask : is the Vref voltage used as reference for sampling each single diff signal (Vin+ and Vin- respect to the GND) or is it used just as reference for the diff signal (Vin+ - Vin-) so i should use also the mid voltage of LTC1992 as Vocm even if it is not related to vref ?

[image: https://i.ibb.co/r6ycyNX/adc.png]

Can this configuration guarantee the best match between the sensor signals and the ADC input ? (use all the full analog input range, with max accuracy)
Am I forgetting something?

Comment: Trying to use the full analogue range of an ADC is folly. Look at the gain, INL and offset errors of your ADC to see why you can never use the full range.

Comment: Sorry, maybe i didn't explain correctly. I want to use all the bits of the adc, but i want to understand if the vref inside the adc is used to compare the difference between the two signals or is used as reference value of each sinle signal. Can i use a Vocm greater than the Vref/2 to measure a Differential signal of (Vref)Vpp ?